# Not able to search a particular string using regular expression in mongodb

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express

I am using node with mongodb and trying to search a particular string.In db there is a string named "xyz limited (xy)" . if i am using the below regular expression-
`.*+xyz limited (xy)+.*` i am unable to find any match but if i use 
`.*+xyz limited+.*` I got one result. Even if i am searching like `.*+(xy)+.*` I got one result but for entire string "xyz limited (xy)" no match found.

Comment: Escape the `(` and `)` to match literal parentheses.

Comment: thanks a lot .. it works fine